# How do I uninstall VMWare Workstation?

Tags: software-installation, vmware-workstation

After an update, I can no longer run VMWare Workstation, it fails to open. Trying to install it fails on the virtual network, the patch no longer works.

How do I uninstall it completely so I can attempt a fresh reinstall?

Comment: @Alvar  Then fix it?

Comment: @tgm4883  great, you fixed the cry for help and the caps issue! :)

Comment: how did u manage to install it? i can install the bundle but can't install the extra's that it ask after opening VMWS

Comment: How did you installed it in first place? What was the error presented?

Answer (score 111, accepted):

VMWare Workstation doesn't ship in a deb, so it isn't registered in dpkg (which is why you can't find it in the software center). It does have an install and uninstall utility though.

To uninstall VMWare Workstation, you will need to run:

```
sudo vmware-installer --uninstall-product vmware-workstation
```

If you just run:

```
vmware-installer
```

by itself, it will print all the options you have available. If you run:

```
vmware-installer -l
```

It will print a list of all VMWare products you have installed.

Similarly, to uninstall VMWare Player:

```
sudo vmware-installer --uninstall-product vmware-player
```

Comment: So, for some reason my install of VMRC broke itself so badly nothing can be installed or uninstalled by VMWare installer. So I've discovered the hard way that this question needs a "nuke" option.

Comment: what to do in these new versions where no vmware-installer api installed ?