# Can't find a program in either software centre or console, want to uninstall it (13.04)

Tags: command-line, 13.04, uninstall

(13.04) I downloaded and installed a program from the internet (.bundle), but it crashes every time I try to run it.

- I can't find it in the software centre
- It doesn't have an "uninstall" option in the dash
- `sudo apt-get remove v` + Tab doesn't list it
- `dpkg --list` doesn't show it either

I need to uninstall it and try installing a different version, but how do I find it?

Comment: Search for uninstallation procedure of that bundle. For example, VMWare and Oracle have their own installation managers.

Comment: @Danatela You should post your comment as an answer since has fixed the problem.

Comment: @Radu, I'm not sure if this would be helpful for others, because OP did not clarify the bundle's name.

Comment: @Danatela heck I would have expected to at least see HOW it was installed. Since that will also answer how to remove it.

Comment: @Danatela I wasn't being sarcastic

Comment: OK, but I just missed the point. So I will try to improve my comment before posting it as an answer. Sorry for my paranoia.

Comment: I should have noted that I am still very new to Ubuntu.
It didn't occur to me yet that there would be so many ways of installing/uninstalling stuff, I just assumed I was doing something wrong, so I never even thought to search for the specific programs uninstall method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, there is no bundle name provided, so I will be general. If you installed something from Internet using `.bundle` or `.run` package, you have to search in Internet the right way to remove that package. For example, VMWare and Oracle have their own installation managers.

### Some common uninstallation procedures for famous packages:

#### NVidia drivers (in case you have installed it through `.run` package)

[Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/219942/how-to-uninstall-manually-installed-nvidia-drivers) is the original answer. Just run `sudo NVIDIA-Linux-XXX-YYY.ZZ.run --uninstall`.

#### ATI drivers

[Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68306/how-do-i-remove-the-propretary-ati-drivers) is the original answer. Run `sudo sh /usr/share/ati/fglrx-uninstall.sh`.

#### Oracle Universal Installer

```
$ORACLE_HOME/oui/bin/runInstaller
```

Note that `ORACLE_HOME` must contain path to Oracle Home directory.

#### VMWare Workstation

Taken from [there](https://askubuntu.com/questions/131045/how-do-i-uninstall-vmware-workstation). Run `vmware-installer --uninstall-product vmware-workstation`.

#### Sources package

In package home directory, run `sudo make uninstall`.

But in most cases, it is better to search for the distribution-provided package or for package in PPA. The exclusion is [Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/download_linux), which recommends install itself using Python script. And it's uninstallation procedure is pretty simple:

```
sudo rm -rf /opt/calibre/*
```

Hope it helps.