# Installing VMware Player

Tags: 14.04, vmware-player

I installed VMware Player-4.0.6-1035888.x86_64 on my x64 Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, but when I run it I get this error message:

> **C header files matching your running kernel were not found.  Refer to your distribution's documentation for installation instructions.**

Now, I've run this beforehand:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

and the folder named `linux-headers-3.13.0-24-generic` exists already in `/usr/src`

Any solutions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://communities.vmware.com/thread/476573

Comment: I had the same error after upgrade to 14.04, but after I run your command, everything worked. I have 6.0.1 build-1379776

Comment: Seems like mine is an old version of vmware player. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix is surely to install the most recent version.

Comment: Kareem's solution (install the most recent version) is still valid for VMware-Player-6.0.3-1895310.x86_64.bundle

Answer (score 2):

Normally this answer above worked, but how about for situation where the kernel gets upgraded?

I upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (lubuntu) and VMWare was requiring a fresh compile.
when it got to "vnet" part, it failed and left me with a non working VM. Ugh!

I removed VMWare (VMware-Player-6.0.1.xxxx) and installed VMware-Player-6.0.2.  The install went smoothly, no questions asked. Back in business.

Gist is: remove VMWare, install it again.

Comment: Here is how to uninstall either Player or Workstation: http://askubuntu.com/questions/131045/how-do-i-uninstall-vmware-workstation

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/include/linux/version.h
```

This should allow vmplayer to find the linux header path automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem, seems like I had downloaded not the latest version. I could only find the latest version through this link.

https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/free#desktop_end_user_computing/vmware_player/6_0

There is a little box at the top of the download page that determines the version you are about to download