# "Vmware Kernel Module Updater" problem in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, kernel, updates, vmware, vmware-workstation

Every time I am trying to launch Vmware-Workstation, I am getting this error message:
[Before you can run Vmware, several modules must be compiled and loaded into the running kernel.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0idSx.png)

After clicking on Install button, I get this:
[Stopping Vmware Services..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0WMz.png)

[Unable to start services. See log file /tmp/vmware-root/vmware-27309.log for details.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WrgPO.png)

I have tried everything to resolve this error but didn't succeeded. Even formatted my laptop and again reinstall ubuntu 16.04 LTS and Vmware-Workstation 12 Pro but this also doesn't make any difference.

This error is really annoying. Someone please help me out...

Answer (score 0):

Download vmmon &vmnet source module for your workstation version from this repository
https://github.com/mkubecek/vmware-host-modules

Answer (score 0):

### Upgrade your "Vmware-Workstation 12 Pro" to "Vmware-Workstation 14.1.1 Pro"

For this,

1. At first [uninstall Vmware-Workstation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/131045/how-do-i-uninstall-vmware-workstation) 12 Pro
2. Then [download Vmware-Workstation 14.1.1 Pro](https://my.vmware.com/en/web/vmware/info/slug/desktop_end_user_computing/vmware_workstation_pro/14_0) and install it.

And hence, it's done!
Enjoy ;)

Comment: Note you'll need a VMware WOrkstation 14 license to use VMware Workstation 14 - 12 -> 14 isn't a free upgrade.